# React Navigation - Initial render of scene inside a StackNavigator has wrong height or position

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a very strange bug in the height or positioning of a scene in a StackNavigator.

- I have a  `BottomTabNavigator` with several `StackNavigators` inside.
- The AppNavigator has `lazy: true`.
- I'm using always a custom header component, set in the `StackNavigator` options `header` key.

The problem occurs when I switch from one tab to the other and the `StackNavigator` first scene renders. It seems the height or the positioning of the scene is off at the beginning and then it gets right.

I've logged the `StackNavigator` options during the re-renders and the only thing that changes when the positioning goes from wrong to right is the layout `minHeight` and `minWidth` that are both 0 in the beginning (wrong position) and have normal values like 751 in the last render (right position).

Any idea what could cause this?

I've attached a gif showing the issue

[image: example]

Comment: It's tough to tell without seeing your code, honestly it looks like there is some sort of screen that it's flashing to start prior to loading the screen you're on.  I'd confirm that you don't have some kind of auth check on the various screens that it might be firing through a render sequence with.

Comment: @JPHorta did you ever figure this out? Experiencing similar issues

Comment: Apparently it's a known bug in react-navigation https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5596 (not fixed yet)